# DevExpress winform: Get Visible Index of focused row

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using window forms devExpress extragrid control and I want to get visible row index of the selected row. In the gridview, there are hundreds of the rows, I scroll down and then select first visible row in the grid, it should give me 0 as visible row index.
I tried the ways in FocusedRowChange event,

```
gridView1.GetVisibleIndex(e.FocusedRowHandle)
```

It should work but surprisingly not working.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **GetVisibleIndex** returns a visible index of a row regardless a scroll position. To calculate a row visible index regarding the top visible row, subtract [TopRowIndex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_TopRowIndextopic) from the returned value.

Answer (score -1):

```
GridCell CurrentCell { get; set ; }
private void gridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
         CurrentCell = null;
        GridHitInfo hitInfo = gridView1.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
        if (hitInfo.HitTest == GridHitTest.RowCell)
        {
            CurrentCell = new GridCell(hitInfo.RowHandle, hitInfo.Column);
        }
    }
}
```

Result: `gridView1.FocusedRowHandle == CurrentCell.RowHandle;`